# ios13 get original image using PHImageManager

Tags: swift, phasset, ios13, phimagemanager

on ios 13 PHImageManagerMaximumSize does not work.

when calling

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
option.isSynchronous = synchronous
option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
option.resizeMode = .exact

manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info) in
})
```

requestImage returns an error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

This code runs fine on ios12

Can you please let me know how to get the original image on ios13?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, although when I request for the thumbnail size image it worked. In fact if you specify any size other than PHImageManagerMaximumSize it'll work. Maybe it's the targetSize issue? btw I don't think it's an issue of deprecated API. It's the same even with code build with iOS12 SDK on iOS13 device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As quoted from Apple's Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanagermaximumsize):

> When you use the PHImageManagerMaximumSize option, Photos provides the largest image available for the asset without scaling or cropping. (That is, it ignores the [resizeMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagerequestoptions/1616988-resizemode) option.)

However in this case, `resizeMode` seems to be in effect on iOS 13.

Setting `resizeMode` to `.none` makes `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` work as expected.

Comment: it also works with .fast resizeMode. We only see the issue when using .exact.

Comment: For those of you who found this solution doesn't work, try setting option.isSynchronous to true.

Comment: Thanks @The1993. I managed to solve it only after I set option.isSynchronious to true

Answer (score 0):

Try `requestImageDataForAsset`, even though its marked as deprecated.
You should also report the `requestImage` issue on iOS 13 to Apple as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are still having problems requesting the original image on iOS 13 try using requestImageDataAndOrientation instead.

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/3237282-requestimagedataandorientation) Suggest that this is the correct way to request the original image data. It returns NSData that you can create an UIImage with if you need that.

Answer (score -1):

`requestImageDataForAsset` is deprecated. zoption.isSynchronous = Yes` would not work in iOS 13.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean, that it does not work anymore. It means that there is a new API you are preferred to use instead and it might be removed in a future release of iOS 13. requestImageDataForAsset still does fully work in iOS 13 in my testing.